# Right-align text with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've an Arabic text and want to move the text to the upper right corner in the image.

I did try using `align='right'` in the code also tried `direction=rtl` but it shows an empty area of the image on the right top corner.

> If you want to try the code make sure to Install [libraqm](https://github.com/HOST-Oman/libraqm) & [raqm](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/depends/install_raqm.sh)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFilter
import textwrap

#configuration
font_size=36
width=3840
height=390
back_ground_color=(255,255,255)
font_size=80
font_color=(0,0,0)
text = " وأيضا هذا النصح محبوب جدا جدا لذلك انا أفضلههذا النص مكتوب باللغةمكتوب باللغةمكتوب باللغةمكتوب باللغةمكتوب باللغة مكتوب باللغة العربية وهو واضح بشكل جميل"
wrapped = textwrap.fill(text, 100)
im  =  Image.new ( "RGB", (width,height), back_ground_color )
draw  =  ImageDraw.Draw ( im )
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("Sahel.ttf", font_size)
draw.text ( (0,0),  wrapped, font=unicode_font, fill=font_color,spacing=30,direction='rtl',align='right',features='rtla')
im.save('text.png')
```

[image: example of output image]

Comment: You can determine the size of rendered text using the [`ImageFont.getsize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize) method. You should be able to use that and the size of the image itself to figure-out where to put the text so it's aligned the way you want.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on how this can be applied with this particular example. @martineau

Comment: If the width of the text in pixels from `getsize()` was `txtw`, and the width of the image was `imgw`, then to right align the text the value of the expression `imgw-txtw` should be used as the X coordinate of the top left corner of the text in the call to [`ImageDraw.text()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text) — assuming the image is wider than the text.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

- The `align` parameter can be used for the smaller lines (usually last one) in order to align them according to the text box
- In order to right align the text box according to the image you need to use the `draw.textsize` function to get the text box size and calculate its position according to your image size.

### Working example with some comments

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import textwrap

# configuration
font_size = 36
width = 3840
height = 390
back_ground_color = (255, 255, 255)
font_size = 80
font_color = (0, 0, 0)
text = " وأيضا هذا النصح محبوب جدا جدا لذلك انا أفضلههذا النص مكتوب باللغةمكتوب باللغةمكتوب باللغةمكتوب باللغةمكتوب باللغة مكتوب باللغة العربية وهو واضح بشكل جميل"
wrapped = textwrap.fill(text, 100)
im = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), back_ground_color)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
unicode_font = ImageFont.truetype("Sahel Regular.ttf", font_size)
# get text box size
text_w, text_h = draw.textsize(wrapped, font=unicode_font, direction="rtl", language="ar")
draw.text(
    # (0, 0),  # top left corner
    # (width - text_w, 0), # top right corner
    # (width - text_w, height - text_h), # bottom right corner
    # (0, height - text_h),  # bottom left corner
    # ((width - text_w) // 2, (height - text_h) // 2),  # center
    (width - text_w, (height - text_h) // 2),  # center vertical + start from right
    wrapped,
    font=unicode_font,
    fill=font_color,
    direction='rtl',
    language='ar',
    align='left',  # affect the second line of the text, set to right to see the last line aligned to the right
)
im.show()
```

### Result

[image]